# Speed Comparison of substring done in code vs Database

Tags: mysql, ssis

I want to import a text file in ssis (SQL Server Integration Services) by applying substring function on the text file itself and load it into different tables. Is this approach faster than importing a text file into table then applying substring function on the table to get the columns required and then insert into other tables?

Comment: and also please give the reason as why it is faster

Comment: YMMV. Test it yourself - if your Integration services machine is crappy and your database beastly, its faster in the database. If the database is under heavy load but the SSIS machine is virtually unused, SSIS will be faster. "how will it perform" is highly dependent on your unique situation.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be faster to do sub-strings on the text file because:

1. You will be inserting less data in the database.
2. You won't have to read the data from a table and put it in another.
3. Database access has to handle transactions and write to logs and all that kind of stuff that slows it down.

It might be slower if:

1. If SSIS is slow doing substrings, but I can't think why it would be.
2. If the database operations make better use of concurrency and multithreading, and therefore run faster than the original import. That is hard to determine.